# How to add App to Choose file in Android Browser

Tags: android, android-intent

When in the Android browser and there is an  tag, it displays "Choose file".  Clicking there gives a list of applications under "Choose file for upload".  How do I register my app to be a choice there? I figure an intent must be registered somehow but I am not seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the IntentFilter that is showing up in the ActivityManager. This will give you a clue.